# Having one part of a SUM() equation be above a certain number

Tags: mysql

So, I currently have a SQL query that brings up a total amount for all orders for a specific customers. This equation is the following.

```
SUM((OrdIt.ItemPrice- OrdIt.DiscountAmount) * OrdIt.Quantity) As TotalAmount
```

However, I only want to display results where the initial `ItemPrice` is OVER 500.

Where would I put `OrdIt.ItemPrice > 500` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could sum a `CASE` expression which checks the price:

```sql
SUM((CASE WHEN OrdIt.ItemPrice > 500
          THEN OrdIt.ItemPrice - OrdIt.DiscountAmount
          ELSE 0 END) * OrdIt.Quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not issue this SQL query?

```
SELECT SUM((OrdIt.ItemPrice - OrdIt.DiscountAmount) * OrdIt.Quantity) As 
TotalAmount
FROM OrdIt
WHERE OrdIt.ItemPrice > 500;
```